# How to log a true result of an Assert

Tags: java, logging, testng, assert

I am writing some tests using TestNG, WebDriver and log4j
I am trying to log the result of an assert nomatter if the result is true or false. For example, when i write this code:

```
Assert.assertTrue(condition)
```

I want to see in the log if that was a PASS or a FAIL. Right now, i can only see any log if the result is a FAIL.
Does anyone have an idea about how can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's an unusual workflow - for unit tests, the tested value is usually only interesting if it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite the Assert-Class and trigger the logger by yourself.

Comment: Do you mean it'd by MyAssert.assertTrue(condition) that would log the result then call into Assert.asserTrue?

Comment: Yes, i meant that. Using MyAssert you can also provide additional logging information, if the logger doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to tell `Assert` to log a successful assertion.  You could do this:

```
Assert.assertTrue(condition);
logger.info(condition ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
```

or subclass `Assert` and reimplement `assertTrue` to do the logging for you.  Note in this case your log line will claim to be inside `Assert.assertTrue` instead of the call point, so you'll have to fix that somehow.

Comment: This is the way i do it right now, but i don't want to write extra code just for logging this. probably the best way to do it is to overwrite the Assert Class, as rollstuhlfahrer said. I thought that i could find a different way which i am not aware about. Thank you guys very much for your fase relpies

Comment: Don't think this'd work, if it fails the log line won't get called.

Comment: @Tom I am not writing unit tests, but selenium tests and sometimes i need to have the asserts certify that some conditions are met and i also want to be able to see this in the logs

Comment: @Tom: the OP says the log already contains the failures.  I put the condition again only because asserts might be turned off (I don't know if `-ea` works on the `Assert` class).

Answer (score 0):

I am working on redesigning TestNG's assert system, take a look at the new architecture and let me know what you think:

https://groups.google.com/group/testng-users/browse_thread/thread/4392868b7d1fd051